# pagefactory with explicit wait in c# for collection of webelements

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

Can anybody tell me how to use explicit wait using pagefactory for a collection of webelements ?

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "tree-item-content")]
public IList<IWebElement> TreeItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you were Java I would point you to AjaxElementLocatorFactory.  But as far as I know, it hasn't been implemented in c#. To see what I am talking about, look [here](http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html) then search for AjaxElementLocatorFactory.

Comment: yeah you are right I figured it out in other way to solve this problem using explicit wait

Answer (score 3):

This solves my issue let me know if this is not a good way to solve the problem

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.WebDriver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(TreeItems)));
```

Comment: Should work. By default all elements are visible. Not the PageObject way though.